# Unknown while loop usage

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

This page a user must choose between one of 2 checkboxes 5 times. So I wrote this:

```
        if (box1a.isSelected() == true || box1b.isSelected() == true) {
            if (box2a.isSelected() == true || box2b.isSelected() == true) {
                if (box3a.isSelected() == true || box3b.isSelected() == true) {
                    if (box4a.isSelected() == true || box4b.isSelected() == true) {
                        if (box5a.isSelected() == true || box5b.isSelected() == true) {


                                 with some other things he does when it is true.


        } else {
            new Error("You must select an answer at all the questions");
        }
```

Then he only returns a error if you don't check one of the top checkboxes. Then cleary I need a while loop in there but i don't know how to uhm do it. I know how a while loop works but don't know how It would look in this situation. Please help

Also now I have to do the same with text fields and using th same methode that I got answered by you guys doesn't work. any advise?

Comment: You don't need while loops. What you need is just just one `if` condition

Comment: Not your question, but the `== true` is redundant.  You can simplify each line to `box1.isSelected() || box2.isSelected()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((box1a.isSelected() || box1b.isSelected()) &&
   (box2a.isSelected() || box2b.isSelected())  &&
   (box3a.isSelected() || box3b.isSelected())  &&
   (box4a.isSelected() || box4b.isSelected())  &&
   (box5a.isSelected() || box5b.isSelected())) 
   {
      //true stuff
   }
   else 
   {
       new Error("You must select an answer at all the questions");
   }
```

You <strike>should never</strike> shouldn't test for true with ==. It is poor style, better to just use the return value from `isSelected()`

Comment: I tried using the same method with my later on question that is text fields didn't work...        if (answer1.getText().length() != 0) 
            &&  (answer2.getText().length() != 0) and tried (>0) any advise?

Comment: @Waldo King, `if (answer1.getText().length() > 0) && (answer2.getText().length() > 0)` will return `true` if there is text in both of the textboxes. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((box1a.isSelected() == true || box1b.isSelected() == true) &&
   (box2a.isSelected() == true || box2b.isSelected() == true) &&
   (box3a.isSelected() == true || box3b.isSelected() == true) &&
   (box4a.isSelected() == true || box4b.isSelected() == true) &&
   (box5a.isSelected() == true || box5b.isSelected() == true)) {
      //DO SOMETHING IF TRUE
}
else {
      new Error("You must select an answer at all the questions");
}
```

No looping needed ^_^

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use radio button (with a default radio button checked) in this case ?

Comment: uhm 2 checkboxes was more user friendly or better look and feal than a radio box but tnx

Comment: well... radio button are done for this case (one needed choice), checkbox are done for multi choice. Think of what peoples know and not what you think to have a better look ;)

Comment: how do you manage the data if the user check two values of the same checkbox group ? Is it what you want ?

Comment: nah I programmed that he can only check one. it's chilled

Comment: Then it's a radio button, not a check box.

Answer (score 0):

A general strategy would be something like this:

```
bool flag = true;
do{
    //search for input
    if (/*the input is valid*/)
        flag = false;
}while (flag);
```

But if you hard code so many options, you might have the wrong design. Try something like a radio button like Jerome C. suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!box1a.isSelected() && !box1b.isSelected()) {
    // You must select an answer at all the questions
}
else if (box1a.isSelected() && box1b.isSelected() && box2a.isSelected() && box2b.isSelected() && box3a.isSelected() && box3b.isSelected() && box4a.isSelected() && box4b.isSelected() && box5a.isSelected() && box5b.isSelected()) {
    // with some other things he does when it is true.
}
```

A few points to note here.

1. Avoid using class names like `Error` as they're normally used for genuine `java.lang.Error` logic.
2. If you have a boolean, you don't need to use a `==` operator.

Comment: thanks that is true. but I'll just always type it double , its not really such a hustle but noted thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want a while-loop.  If you are thinking that the user must "stay in the loop" while the your condition (all 5 questions answered) is not met, then it is unnecessary.  The Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) will continue running the "loop" for you.

On the other hand, if you are looking for a compact way to verify all of your checkboxes, you can change how they are declared from (assuming) javax.swing.JCheckbox box1a; etc. to either a fixed array or an ArrayList which you can then iterate over with a for-loop.